# wrap a .less css definitions in a namespace

Tags: css, less

I wanted to use twitter bootstrap CSS only in a specific element in my web page.

I tried to do it like in code below. But after compiling this to a css file nothing was outputted. If I moved `@import` outside `#my_div` then I got all css definitions for twitter boostrap.

```
#my_div {
    @import "../twitter_bootstrap/lib/bootstrap.less";
}
```

How can I namespace a `less css` file?

Answer (score 23):

I am not using `less` on the live site, nor am I manually doing the compiling so this is kind of a "simple" version. It's not as automated as the others but may apply to some users.

1. Edit `bootstrap.css` / `bootstrap-responsive.css`

   ```
   .tb {
     // copy/paste the entire bootstrap.css
   }
   ```
2. Recompile with less or use an online less compiler - http://winless.org/online-less-compiler
3. Edit the now-compiled file and change `body {}` CSS declarations to `tb {}`.
4. Use the new CSS file.
5. Place your "bootstrapped" content inside a `<div class='tb'></div>`

Comment: How would this prevent collisions in html, for example: <div class="large-button"></div> When another library has a class definition of 'large-button'? Prefixing is the only way to prevent namespace collisions on both ends.

Comment: I had previously tried using by using all the .less files in the source code and recompiling with winless. However, something was missing in the final CSS file. I was able to correct it by following your procedure -- thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. I followed the instructions under "Installing Grunt" at getbootstrap.com/getting-started. Once that was working, I followed this answer, recompiling with `grunt dist`. This way, I maintain CSS vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 11):

LESS documentation has a section about [namespaces](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-namespaces).

So you could define your lib in a separate document:

```
#ns {
  .twitter () {
    // Instructions to be used later
    // Nothing will appear in compiled CSS except if called later (because of parenthesis)
  }
}
```

import this file at the beginning of the CSS file to be compiled and use these instructions:

```
#my_div {
  #ns > .twitter;
}
```

Comment: The problem is with `@import`. It doesn't work when using it in a namespace.

Comment: @MartinsBalodis The code for lib should be a LESS file (just add `#ns { .anything () {` at the beginning and two `}` at the end of your CSS lib. And the main file must also be a LESS file. The import should take place at the beginning outside `#my_div {}`. Nothing from the first file will be outputted without further instruction, so you can import it anywhere before this selector. Then the `#ns > .twitter;` instruction will finally add your code right where you want to.

Comment: The twitter lib can only be imported. I cannot edit those files. They are used as git submodule. [Twitter modules main .less file](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/lib/bootstrap.less)

Comment: Thanks!  It worked!! For those making a first attempt, here is a fork with a modified makefile and notes for compiling:  https://github.com/majgis/bootstrap/blob/master/notes.txt

Comment: For anyone that just wants a quick file to work with, here is a compiled version of v2.2.2 using a ".tbs" namespace class. https://gist.github.com/4504997

Answer (score 4):

This is how I have done it. This takes place in the root of the bootstrap folder that is downloaded, or cloned from git.

```
## ./less/namespace.css (New file)

#ns {
  .twitter() {
    @import "less/bootstrap.less";
  }
}

## ./style.less

@import "less/namespace.less";

.namespace {
  #ns > .twitter;
}
```

Then run less style.less > style.css

Comment: what's in the less/namespace.less file?

Comment: I tried this, but I can't use imported mixins from .twitter()

Comment: This doesn't work, you end up with selectors like: button.namespace .close {...}

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it, based on majgis's github fork above:

bootstrap-ns.less:

```
@import "namespace.less"
.bs {
    #ns > .twitter;
    }
```

namespace.less:

```
#ns {
  .twitter(){
    @import "bootstrap.less";
  }
}
```

You then reference bootstrap-ns.less in your html page. This was tested with dotLESS.

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over the compilation parameters just set `strictImports` to false and work as you intended to everything should be fine. consider looking at [less-strictimports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763392/less-strictimports) or at this [issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/656).