# LESS strictImports

Tags: import, less

I have a build that compiles several less files (all are actually imported into one master.less file). One of the options for the build is **strictImports** which suggests that it forces the evaluation of imports. Does anyone know if this have to do with operations in imported files, or am I completely missing the point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `strictImports` controls whether the compiler will allow an `@import` *inside* of either `@media` blocks or (a later addition) other *selector* blocks. See some of the comments from [this closed issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/656) with regards to that.

So with it set to `true` these are ***not*** allowed:

```
@media screen {
   @import somefile.less;
}
.mySelector {
   @import somefile.less;
}
```

Comment: Ha. It appears as though I was missing the point. Thank you for the clarification and the link.