# Using bootstrap only in a special div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap in my TYPO3 frontend plugin, but I only want to use it in a special div, so that the class `without_bootstrap` won't be touched from the bootstrap classes.

For example

```
<div class="without_bootstrap">
     <div class="with_bootstrap">
     </div>
</div>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: use custom class name for div in which u dont want to use bootstrap....As  bootstrap apply js and css to only standard pre-defined names....and most  important dont forget to use external .css and .js file to override styles and scripts for global tags  which are defined in bootstrap plugin such as h,a etc....

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: @AnuragGoel BS styles body and many other elements afaik, not only .form-input, its grid(s) and so on. So I don't see how you'd not apply BS to a whole page by just adding non-BS classes to some elements...

Comment: OP Do you use a preprocessor like LESS or Sass? Can you edit Bootstrap CSS file? You could apply top voted answer from this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10971228/137626) or mine

Comment: possible duplicate of [wrap a .less css definitions in a namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288463/wrap-a-less-css-definitions-in-a-namespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially. If you avoid class names that are used by bootstrap, you should be fine. But bootstrap defines some tag-specific styles, such as

```
a {
  background-color: transparent
}
```

You can circumvent that by defining a style like that:

```
.without-bootstrap > a {
  /* whatever */
}
```

Example:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:#f00;
}
.no-bootstrap > a {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="no-bootstrap">
    <a href="#"> No Bootstrap</a>
    <div class="bootstrap">
      <a href="#"> With Bootstrap</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution might be to customize bootstrap for your needs:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: okay thanks, but in my case its not really suitable to do it in this ways. Is there a possibility to do it from the other way? can I kaplse bootstrap?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish anyway. In general bootstrap's style definition are not that destructive to have any need to overwrite them.

Comment: Yes you can use iframe in place of  div in which another webpage loads up with different css and js....and @mmgross is Right...

Comment: Iframe won't work.

I have a fully finished and styled page. And a new typo3 frontend plugin wich uses BS, so now this plugin overwirdes my page css.

Comment: not that destructive > well, `* { box-sizing: border-box}` has a huge impact if you aren't already using this box model! (edit: I'd advise against using both models on the same page. Headaches incoming)

Comment: just remove css from that plugin and apply your style in my opinion is best option rather than finding some workaround for bad plugin.